# How to tell Google that each subfolder is a different site? Otherwise, Google appends the main site's name to every other subfolder

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, title, internationalization

One of our Korean clients (who would like to remain unamed) has a problem with their section of their website (subfolder). They are part of an international organization. Let's call them "Foobar" for our purposes.

### The setup

`www.foobar.com` (redirects to country site ie. `www.foobar.com/usa/` if IP is detected from USA)

`www.foobar.com/usa/` title tag shows `<title>Foobar USA</title>`

`www.foobar.com/korea/` title tag shows `<title>Foobar Korea</title>`

`www.foobar.com/japan/` title tag shows `<title>Foobar Japan</title>`

`www.foobar.com/international/en/` title tag shows `<title>Foobar International</title>`

### The problem

In Google's SERP, when searching "foobar korea" (for example), their pages under `www.foobar.com/korea/` show up in search results with the `Foobar USA` appended to the titles of all countries' subfolder pages in the SERP (ie. `Lorem Ipsum - Foobar Korea - Foobar USA` instead of the original `<title>Lorem Ipsum - Foobar Korea</title>`). We don't mind the rewrite. Our problem is how do we tell Google that this subfolder belongs to `Foobar Korea` and not `Foobar USA`?

From our own experience, after Google realizes that the organization name already appears in the title tag, they don't append it again.

This problem also appears in other country sites like Japan, China, etc.

It seems like Google is convinced that the entire domain is `Foobar USA`. Since Googlebot [crawls from mostly US IP addresses](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6144055?hl=en), when the crawler tries to get the root domain `www.foobar.com`, it gets 301 redirected to `www.foobar.com/usa/` where it finds `<title>Foobar USA</title>` and this is exactly what is appended to every subfolder page title where it doesn't exist.

### Our failed attempts

We have tried adding **structured data** to the HTML pages with the name Foobar Korea, but that had no effect.

We registered the property separately in Google Search Console, but that has no effect.

We also have registered the www.foobar.com/korea/ as a **Google My Business** with the name Foobar Korea.

Are there any other ways to let Google know that these are **separate sites** and not to use the same title for all subfolders?

### Alternative solutions

1. From our own experience with another client, we know that if we change the main site `www.foobar.com/usa/` to be just `<title>Foobar</title>` (essentially letting Google think that it is just `Foobar` and not `Foobar USA`), Google will append just `Foobar` to all subfolder page titles if that doesn't already exist in the title.
2. As @closetnoc mentioned in the comments, we can also try changing the title length of the main page from `<title>Foobar Korea</title>` to something like `<title>Doing more foo than bar - Foobar Korea</title>` to discourage Google from appending the incorrect site name. From our experience also, this works, but is seems more like hiding the problem instead of fixing the problem.

The best solution is to signal to Google that each subfolder is a different site.

*Just to be clear: This issue is not about rewriting the whole title in SERP. This issue is about Google appending the incorrect organization name to the title. The question is asking how to let Google know that this subfolder is a different organization.*

### EDIT: November 27th

It's finally fixed. See [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/111057/59798)

Comment: Google My Business is for local searches with 'SNACK' box results and not organics, they are not subject to `<title>`, only organics.

Comment: @SimonHayter I edited the post. Could you see if this makes the question unique? Our goal is to tell Google that **this subfolder is a different organization**. We tried GMB hoping it'd be a signal to Google *hey, this is our name*. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like Google is trying to brand your SERP link in what may be a way I have not seen before or do not recall. Can we get a more realistic example of a pages title tag? I suspect this can be controlled, however, to be sure I would need a title example that is realistic. If you do not want to give away the company name, Tha is fine, however, please give us an example name that is the same length as your current name. As well, how do page title tags vary from page to page? Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc The examples listed in the question are pretty much exactly how the title tags look in reality for those pages. Unfortunately, the client is not allowing us to share their name.

One note: we do know that Googlebot crawls from mostly US IP address and that is why when Google crawls the root domain `foobar.com`, they get a 301 redirect to `foobar.com/usa` subfolder where they find `<title>Foobar USA</title>` and this is exactly what is being appended to all other subfolders.

Comment: So we **know** where Google is getting `Foobar USA` from. We just want a way to tell Google that that is only applicable for that one subfolder.

Comment: I suspect your title tags are too short. It is interesting that Google sees foobar usa, however, I suspect Google is taking foobar usa as a brand and appending that on a too short title tag. Manage your title tags between 45 and 55 characters and no longer than 60 characters. Test this and you will likely see the problem go away.

Comment: I used to test this using Google Search Console and Fetch as Google. It gives you example SERP links. These may not always reflect reality, however, it is a reasonable real-time tool that you can use. Change a failed title tag, test with Fetch as Google and see what you get. Please understand that the SERPs are NOT real-time! It takes a couple of days before the regular googlebot visits the page and updates the SERP link for real. Well worth testing!!

Comment: Do you use a sitemap? https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en

Comment: Why are using country names in your title at all?   I'd recommend just using "Foobar" as the title of your homepage no matter which country it is targeting.   You don't usually need the target country in the title at all.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the main page of each subfolder will be its site name because every country will spell the name in their own local language.

Comment: @closetnoc We can try to advise our client to add more text to their main subfolder page title in Korea so it doesn't just say `Foobar Korea` and says something like `Doing more foo than any bar - Foobar Korea`. It is also from our experience that with some of the pages with longer optimized titles, they get left alone.

Comment: @closetnoc However, changing the title length is not really solving the problem. It is just trying to hide the problem. The problem is Google still thinks the site name is true for every subfolder.

Comment: Unfortunately, these days, with Google being all squirrelly and deciding what titles are worthy and what not along with branding, if you are not managing your title length, your are leaving your future in someone else's hands. This is why I recommend learning how to manage titles. Not covering the problem. Just managing the reality we must face when dealing with a 900 pound gorilla in a monopoly position. They, of course, are far smarter than you and your title tags simply will not do! Get with the program. Straighten up and fly right. Momma says so. (Humor) Cheers!!

Comment: "Folder" is a Microsoft Windows-ism that should never be applied to the internet. Call them what they are: directories. Folders are **not** the same thing.

Comment: @Rob Actually folders started with Sparq before Microsoft... after all, Microsoft ripped off the Sparq interface. But your point is correct. Folders is really a GUI term and not a Unix, Linux, or other non-Windows OS term which is where the web/Internet gets it's terms.

Comment: @Rob I agree with you, but it is just semantics. Even Moz uses "[folder](https://moz.com/learn/seo/url)" terminology. I'm not saying that that justifies it, but it is very similar to the discussion of URI/URN/URL. For me, "folder" seems a bit more digestible for people.

Comment: @JosephShih Yes. As I said, kids who grew up with Windows and didn't learn computer science till later. A folder is not a directory as closetnoc pointed out.

Comment: Thanks all. The title has been fixed. See [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/111057/59798).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We checked today on November 29th and the title in the SERP no longer has the `- Foobar USA` appended to the end. It is now just `Foobar Korea` (not `Foobar Korea - Foobar USA`).

#### Here is what we did

- October 27th (Day 0) - Added the following **structured data**:

  ```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "https://www.foobar.com/korea/",
  "name": "Foobar Korea"
  }
  </script>
  ```
- November 20th (Day 24) - Posted question here on Stack Exchange after **no results**.
- November 24th (Day 28) - Our own research led us to add **noodp** `<meta name="robots" content="noodp">`. We are not sure if this really had any effect. It basically [tells search engines not to use info from public directories](https://moz.com/community/q/meta-robot-tag-index-follow-noodp-noydir) as they may be outdated.
- November 29th (Day 33) - **Success!** We checked Google SERP and the subfolder homepage `www.foobar.com/korea/` no longer has the `- Foobar USA` appended to the end.

#### Extra notes

- Even though we advised our client to annotate their pages with hreflang annotations, till this day, they have not yet done it. For the record, **hreflang annotations** was NOT used.
- Title length was not changed. Page `www.foobar.com/korea/` is still `<title>Foobar Korea</title>`.
- No de-indexing and then re-indexing tactic was used.

Answer (score 4):

Within another context I have given these examples of how to use `hreflang` and `canonical` links. For your purpose I added *structural data in the head section* of both examples with meta tags indicating an organization name, brand and department:

**Example of an English webpage**

`http://example.com/en/`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
     <title>English webpage</title>
     <meta content="My English Organization" itemprop="name">
     <meta content="My English Brand Name" itemprop="brand">
     <meta content="My English Department" itemprop="department">
     <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/en">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/" hreflang="en">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/nl/" hreflang="nl">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/" hreflang="x-default">
</head>
<body>
     <p>This is a webpage written in English. 
        This page is also available in Dutch. 
        The default language of this page is English. 
</body>
</html>
```

**Example of a Dutch webpage**

`http://example.com/nl/`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl"> 
<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
     <title>Nederlandse webpagina</title> 
     <meta content="My Dutch Organization" itemprop="name">
     <meta content="My Dutch Brand Name" itemprop="brand">
     <meta content="My Dutch Department" itemprop="department">
     <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/nl" >
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/" hreflang="en">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/nl/" hreflang="nl">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/" hreflang="x-default">
</head>
<body>
     <p>Dit is een Nederlandstalige web pagina. 
        Deze pagina is beschikbaar in het Engels. 
        De standaardtaal van deze pagina is Engels.
</body>
</html>
```

This should be enough for Google to determine which page to use for a given locale. The canonical link is important.

**Structured data could be used in the `head` section**, although search engines may consume this data as they wish. In my examples I added a `type` 'Organization' in the head in microdata format, and some properties of this type: `name`, `brand`, and `department`. If have checked my examples using  [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#); in this way you can check the interpretation of your data. The result in GSDTT of the first example - which looks good to me - is:

```
@type Organization
 name My English Organization
 brand
    @type Thing
     name My English Brand Name
 department
    @type Organization
     name My English Department
```

It is up to you which properties from `Organization` you use. `name` seems most appropriate to me at first glance. You can find a full list of valid properties for this type at [schema.org/Organization](http://schema.org/Organization).

Additionally, I would recommend [to create a sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668), and update it when appropriate.

Comment: I added a recommendation to build a sitemap in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your example. The issue is not about which page to serve on Google. We have already advised on correctly annotating their pages with hreflang annotations. **The main question is how do we indicate to Google that each subfolder is a different organization.** Thanks again.

Comment: As a second thought, maybe you should use structured data in your case. First of al, I think you should describe the properties of the page, `hreflang` only hints to alternative languages. I have not tested the update of my answer, but it might work. Keep me updated.

Comment: @JosephShih It might also help to create some adds (AddWords) for each organization. If even this does not help: call Google! I am sure they will help you getting where you want to be. I am always surprised how well Google support employees are willing to help an how well they are trained, at least in The Netherlands. I did not put this advice in my answer, since this is not a programming advice, but it might help you.

Comment: @JosephShih I updated my answer with structured data.

Comment: Note: `<meta>` and `<link>` tags do not use or need a closing slash and never have.

Comment: @iep Thanks, but the original question already notes that Structured Data has already been added and are using Schema.org Organization.

Comment: @JosephShih sure, but I think there’s a combination of things that should be right in order to get things work, The reason I try to formulate an answer on your question is because it is an issue  that has also become important to me last weeks. Would be great to have a definite, working answer. It’s pretty hard to test, though...

Comment: Maybe this whole issue ends up in a scenario in which different organizations within the same domain should have their own subdomain and SSL certificates. Localization, alternative links and structured data might still be necessary. Yet, bot subdomains and their SSL certifates give tons of possibilties to articulate your organization name. It seems a structural solution to me, although I do understand that your question is about solving the problem with URL's, not with subdomains and certificates.

Comment: @iep Thanks. Yeah, subdomain is one solution, but at their DA and the size of their organization, that is most likely not an option for them. I agree, having everything right is the only way, but so far, we have tried everything. We previously fixed the title appending issue with another client already, but this case is challenging.

Comment: @JosephShih Well, at least you have a set of good discussions in the answers you’ve got, which you can communicate with the organizations involved.

Comment: Thanks all. The title has been fixed. See [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/111057/59798).

Answer (score 2):

It is quite difficult to determine the cause without examining the source code.

- I assume that your website has errors with **[canonical](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)** meta
  links. Your web page for Korea www.foobar.com/korea/ should have
  `<link rel="canonical" href="www.foobar.com/korea/foobar-korea.html"
  />`.
- If your website is multi-lingual then use **[meta hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)**.
- Also check your **[code 301](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)**. Maybe there are mistakes.

*Addition*

> The main question is how do we indicate to Google that each subfolder is a different organization.

**[7 Common Hreflang Mistakes (and How to Fix Them) + Bonus Tip](https://www.semrush.com/blog/7-common-hreflang-mistakes-and-how-to-fix-them/)**:

> **Not Using Canonical Tags and Hreflang Tags Together Correctly**. The hreflang tag also can be used along with rel="canonical" annotations, but hreflang tags need to reference self-referential canonical URLs. For example, page A should have a canonical tag pointing to page A, page B should have a canonical tag pointing to page B, and page C should have a canonical tag pointing to page C. All three pages should have hreflang tags that mention all three of the pages in the group. You do NOT want to canonicalize only one version of a page in a page grouping, as that would interfere with hreflang annotations.

Apply meta hreflang and canonical to USA:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.foobar.com/usa/main.html" />
<link rel="alternate" href="www.foobar.com/usa/main.html" hreflang="en-us" />
<link rel="alternate" href="www.foobar.com/korea/main.html" hreflang="ko" />
```

Apply meta hreflang and canonical to Korea:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.foobar.com/korea/main.html" />
<link rel="alternate" href="www.foobar.com/korea/main.html" hreflang="ko" />
<link rel="alternate" href="www.foobar.com/usa/main.html" hreflang="en-us" />
```

Read more: **[Lang unicode](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_territory_information.html)** ++ **[Getting hreflang Right: Examples and Insights for International SEO (Moz)](https://moz.com/blog/hreflang-behaviour-insights)** ++ **[Hreflang и Canonical International SEO Test](http://www.stateofdigital.com/hreflang-canonical-test/)**.

Apply structured data - property Organization for United States:

```
<section vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Organization">
<h1 property="name">Name</h1>
<p property=areaServed>(The geographic area where a service or offered item is providedfor example:) Throughout on the United States</p>
<section property="address" typeof="PostalAddress">
<h2 property="name">Main address</h2>
<p property="streetAddress">Address</p>
<p property="postalCode">Code</p>
<p property="addressLocality">City</p>
<p>USA<meta property=addressCountry content=US /></p>
</section>
```

Apply structured data - property Organization for South Korea:

```
<section vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Organization">
<h1 property="name">Name</h1>
<p property=areaServed>(The geographic area where a service or offered item is providedfor example:) Throughout on the South Korea</p>
<section property="address" typeof="PostalAddress">
<h2 property="name">Main address</h2>
<p property="streetAddress">Address</p>
<p property="postalCode">Code</p>
<p property="addressLocality">City</p>
<p>South Korea<meta property=addressCountry content=KR /></p>
</section>
```

Read more **[ISO 3166-2 of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, our canonicals are correct for every page. We have advised our clients to annotate their different subfolder pages with appropriate hreflang annotations. The 301 HTTP response I already analyzed. **The main question is how do we indicate to Google that each subfolder is a different organization.** Thanks again.

Comment: Note: `<meta>` and `<link>` tags do not use or need a closing slash and never have.

Comment: @Rob The example 2 of http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification in which the closing slashes are used

Comment: @nikant25 Thanks, but the original question already notes that Structured Data has already been added and are using Schema.org Organization.

Comment: @nikant25 You should follow [the actual HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) and not a third party site. Nowhere in the history of HTML have those tags used or needed a closing slash or any example ever shown of such within the specification. In fact, the specification states that, putting one there has no meaning, does nothing, and browsers are instructed to ignore it.

Comment: @Rob Yes you are right.

Comment: Thanks all. The title has been fixed. See [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/111057/59798).

Comment: -1. The `<link rel="canonical" href="...">` tags in this answer are completely wrong. Should add schema at the start of the link or remove the host name. Now they are relative paths pointing to a sub-directory `www.foobar.com`.